# Punkt not found

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

I just started natural language processing and I would like to know how to run **word_tokenize** & **sent_tokenize** properly. I know python already suggested doing the following

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

But our proxy prevents us to "download" using python.
Luckily, I can download the files via http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

And I tried creating nltk_data and extract punkt there but the problem still persist. I would like to know how to correct this problem with your expertise.

[image: abcd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

Instead of putting **punkt** under **nltk_data**, you should create a new folder inside **nltk_data** labelled "**tokenizers**" where **punkt** should be placed inside

Example:

```
C:\Users\(username)\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt
```